# Group dataframe using start and end column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have thousands of recordings. I want to group the dataframe by setting starting column value(1st column) being 'B' till ending value being 'B' but ending 'B' not included.
I want to work on data which is between 'B' and till 'B'. How can I do that using pandas?

```
B,0,15000.000000,716.881652,-0.065916 
K,0,-33,1,4030
K,1,-16,2,4028
K,2,-18,12,4036
K,3,-14,-3,4054
P,0,-452,4089,329
P,1,-428,4082,427
P,2,-382,4078,518
P,3,-363,4052,545
P,4,-347,4064,508
K,4,-2,17,4048
K,5,-18,12,4048
P,5,-373,4068,409
B,1,16000.000000,715.443420,-0.067204
K,6,-16,-2,4054
P,6,-433,4082,390
K,7,-16,4,4036
P,7,-457,4104,406
B,2,17000.000000,716.930297,-0.084369
```

Expected output:

`df1`:

```
B,0,15000.000000,716.881652,-0.065916 
K,0,-33,1,4030
K,1,-16,2,4028
K,2,-18,12,4036
K,3,-14,-3,4054
P,0,-452,4089,329
P,1,-428,4082,427
P,2,-382,4078,518
P,3,-363,4052,545
P,4,-347,4064,508
K,4,-2,17,4048
K,5,-18,12,4048
P,5,-373,4068,409
```

`df2`:

```
B,1,16000.000000,715.443420,-0.067204
K,6,-16,-2,4054
P,6,-433,4082,390
K,7,-16,4,4036
P,7,-457,4104,406
```

Comment: Your expected output doesn't group the dataframe by column `B` though..

Comment: Basically you want to split your dataframe into chunks from one `B` (start, included) to the next `B` (end, not included). Or do you only need that first chunk till a 2nd `B` appears?

Comment: @Rabinzel Yes, to split your data frame into multiple chunks from one B (start, included) to the next B (end, not included). I have edited the expected output.

Comment: Did the answer I have posted below helped?

Comment: @gtomer No, I am getting an error. "KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: "

Comment: see my answer. No need for storing them into a dictionary, but it is one possibility

Comment: I have corrected my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply look up the (numerical) indices where the column contains `'B'`, then split your `df` into a list `subdfs` accordingly:

```py
ix = df.reset_index().index[df[0] == 'B'].tolist()
subdfs = [df.iloc[a:b] for a, b in zip(ix, ix[1:] + [None])]
>>> len(subdfs)
3
```

### Explanation

The first bit gets us the numerical indices where column `0` contains `'B'`:

```py
ix = df.reset_index().index[df[0] == 'B'].tolist()
>>> ix
[0, 13, 18]
```

It is important to use `.iloc` for the splitting, not `.loc`, so that `df.iloc[a:b]` includes row `a` but excludes row `b`. We also add a `None` for the last subdf so that one goes from the last index of `'B'` til the end of the `df`:

```py
subdfs = [df.iloc[a:b] for a, b in zip(ix, ix[1:] + [None])]
>>> subdfs[0]
    0  1        2            3            4
0   B  0  15000.0   716.881652    -0.065916
1   K  0    -33.0     1.000000  4030.000000
2   K  1    -16.0     2.000000  4028.000000
3   K  2    -18.0    12.000000  4036.000000
4   K  3    -14.0    -3.000000  4054.000000
5   P  0   -452.0  4089.000000   329.000000
6   P  1   -428.0  4082.000000   427.000000
7   P  2   -382.0  4078.000000   518.000000
8   P  3   -363.0  4052.000000   545.000000
9   P  4   -347.0  4064.000000   508.000000
10  K  4     -2.0    17.000000  4048.000000
11  K  5    -18.0    12.000000  4048.000000
12  P  5   -373.0  4068.000000   409.000000

>>> subdfs[-1]
    0  1        2           3         4
18  B  2  17000.0  716.930297 -0.084369
```

**Note**: This also works if `df` has an Index that is not a simple `RangeIndex`:

```py
# test for 'a', 'b', ... index
from string import ascii_lowercase

df = df.set_axis(list(ascii_lowercase[:df.shape[0]]))

# repeat code above

>>> subdfs[0]
   0  1        2            3            4
a  B  0  15000.0   716.881652    -0.065916
b  K  0    -33.0     1.000000  4030.000000
c  K  1    -16.0     2.000000  4028.000000
d  K  2    -18.0    12.000000  4036.000000
e  K  3    -14.0    -3.000000  4054.000000
f  P  0   -452.0  4089.000000   329.000000
g  P  1   -428.0  4082.000000   427.000000
h  P  2   -382.0  4078.000000   518.000000
i  P  3   -363.0  4052.000000   545.000000
j  P  4   -347.0  4064.000000   508.000000
k  K  4     -2.0    17.000000  4048.000000
l  K  5    -18.0    12.000000  4048.000000
m  P  5   -373.0  4068.000000   409.000000
```

### Addendum: using `groupby`

Here is an even more concise way of doing the split into groups:

```py
subdfs = [g for i, g in df.groupby((df[0] == 'B').cumsum()) if i > 0]
```

**How does it work?**

The inner part `df[0] == 'B'` is our usual condition marking the beginning of a group. Then, doing the `.cumsum()` of that implicitly converts `bool` into `int` (with `False: 0` and `True: 1`), which gives a unique int (1, 2, 3, ...) for each group of rows starting with a `'B'` row. As a "bonus", we also get a possible group `0` for all rows before the first `'B'` row, but in this context we reject that possible group with `if i > 0`. Finally, we `.groupby()` that value and use the iterator form `.groupby().__iter__` to get all the groups.

Comment: Adding None helps. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it like that:

```
df = df.reset_index()
x = df.iloc[:,0]] == 'B'
df.loc[x[x].index[0]:x[x].index[1]-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the indices, then store chunks of the df with the right boundaries to a dict (for example).

Input data looks like this:

```
   key  val1     val2         val3         val4
0    B     0  15000.0   716.881652    -0.065916
1    K     0    -33.0     1.000000  4030.000000
2    K     1    -16.0     2.000000  4028.000000
3    K     2    -18.0    12.000000  4036.000000
4    K     3    -14.0    -3.000000  4054.000000
5    P     0   -452.0  4089.000000   329.000000
6    P     1   -428.0  4082.000000   427.000000
7    P     2   -382.0  4078.000000   518.000000
8    P     3   -363.0  4052.000000   545.000000
9    P     4   -347.0  4064.000000   508.000000
10   K     4     -2.0    17.000000  4048.000000
11   K     5    -18.0    12.000000  4048.000000
12   P     5   -373.0  4068.000000   409.000000
13   B     1  16000.0   715.443420    -0.067204
14   K     6    -16.0    -2.000000  4054.000000
15   P     6   -433.0  4082.000000   390.000000
16   K     7    -16.0     4.000000  4036.000000
17   P     7   -457.0  4104.000000   406.000000
18   B     2  17000.0   716.930297    -0.084369
```

```py
# in my df first column is named 0 where I search for "B"
# you need to replace that to whatever name your columns has there
boundaries = df[df['key'] == 'B'].index.tolist()
print(f"{boundaries=}")
# [0, 13, 18]

out = {}
for idx, (start,end) in enumerate(zip(boundaries[:-1], boundaries[1:]), 1):
    print(f"{idx=} , {start=} , {end=}")
    out[f"df{idx}"] = df.loc[start:end-1]
    
print(out)
```

Output:

```
boundaries=[0, 13, 18]
idx=1 , start=0 , end=13
idx=2 , start=13 , end=18

{'df1':    key  val1     val2         val3         val4
0    B     0  15000.0   716.881652    -0.065916
1    K     0    -33.0     1.000000  4030.000000
2    K     1    -16.0     2.000000  4028.000000
3    K     2    -18.0    12.000000  4036.000000
4    K     3    -14.0    -3.000000  4054.000000
5    P     0   -452.0  4089.000000   329.000000
6    P     1   -428.0  4082.000000   427.000000
7    P     2   -382.0  4078.000000   518.000000
8    P     3   -363.0  4052.000000   545.000000
9    P     4   -347.0  4064.000000   508.000000
10   K     4     -2.0    17.000000  4048.000000
11   K     5    -18.0    12.000000  4048.000000
12   P     5   -373.0  4068.000000   409.000000, 
'df2':    key  val1     val2        val3         val4
13   B     1  16000.0   715.44342    -0.067204
14   K     6    -16.0    -2.00000  4054.000000
15   P     6   -433.0  4082.00000   390.000000
16   K     7    -16.0     4.00000  4036.000000
17   P     7   -457.0  4104.00000   406.000000}
```

Explanation:
in boundaries you select the first column and search for all the rows in your df, where the value is `B`. With `index.tolist()` you only get the indices of the rows where this condition is true.

The logic behind the next step is loop through this list of indices with [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). Both arguments of zip loop through the same list, but `end` is shifted by one. Like that you can access those list elements pairwise.
Then you filter your dataframe with loc to get the rows between start and end.
[enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is used to get an increasing counter every loop (starting at 1, like I defined in the 2nd argument of it) to create a different key every loop and store the new dataframe with that key.

Comment: every value to a key in that dictionary is an own dataframe. so instead of df1 and df2 you have out[0], out[1]. the name of the key are from enumerate, you can name them as you like. is it that what you mean?

Comment: Thank you, this helped! Could you please tell me what is going on here? As I am new to this trying to understand it.

Comment: updated my answer with more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = """
B,0,15000.000000,716.881652,-0.065916 
K,0,-33,1,4030
K,1,-16,2,4028
K,2,-18,12,4036
K,3,-14,-3,4054
P,0,-452,4089,329
P,1,-428,4082,427
P,2,-382,4078,518
P,3,-363,4052,545
P,4,-347,4064,508
K,4,-2,17,4048
K,5,-18,12,4048
P,5,-373,4068,409
B,1,16000.000000,715.443420,-0.067204
K,6,-16,-2,4054
P,6,-433,4082,390
K,7,-16,4,4036
P,7,-457,4104,406
B,2,17000.000000,716.930297,-0.084369
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=',', header=None)
index = pd.Series(df[df[0] == "B"].index)
pd.concat([index, index.shift(-1).fillna(-1)], axis=1).astype(int).apply(lambda x: df[slice(x[0], x[1])], axis=1)
```